# Regex doesn't recognize underscore as special character

Tags: regex

```
/(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*[_!@#$%^&*-])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/
```

I'm trying to make a regex for password validation such that the password must be at least 8 chars and include one uppercase, one lowercase, one number, and one special char. It works fine except it won't recognize the underscore (_) as a special character. I.e., Pa$$w0rd matches, but Pass_w0rd doesn't. Thoughts?

Comment: The answer is really very simple.  You did not include `_` in your special characters.

Comment: That is some really wicked looking regex. Are you sure you want to use regex for something like this? It may become hard to maintain as requirements change.

Comment: David B, actually because this regex uses lookahead assertions it's probably fine for maintainability.  Each part is modular and does not rely on any other part.

Comment: I already wondered how a regex could ensure that a string includes all of several sets of characters and has a minimum length. +1 for the question and explanation because this is a really cool approach I didn't think of yet. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This portion of the regex seems to be looking for special characters:

```
(?=.*[!@#$%^&*-])
```

Note that the character class does not include an underscore, try changing this to the following:

```
(?=.*[_!@#$%^&*-])
```

You will also need to modify or remove this portion of the regex:

```
(?=.*\W+)
```

`\W` is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so if an underscore is your only special character this portion of the regex will cause it to fail.  Instead, change it to the following (or remove it, it is redundant since you already check for special characters earlier):

```
(?=.*[^\w_])
```

Complete regex:

```
/(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*[_!@#$%^&*-])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\w_])(?![.\n])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to include that revision in my code snippet. It still doesn't accept Pass_w0rd :(

Answer (score 2):

This one here works as well. It defines a special character as by excluding alphanumerical characters and whitespace, so it includes the underscore:

```
(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[\d])(?=.*?[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}
```

Comment: This seems to work well for all characters. But does not take space

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the only thing that could possibly satisfy the `\W`, by definition, is something other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. The underscore is specifically not matched by `\W`, and in `Pass_w0rd`, nothing else is matched by it, either.

I suspect that having both your specific list of special characters *and* the `\W` is overkill. Pick one and you're likely to be happier. I also recommend splitting this whole thing up into several separate tests for much better maintainability.

Comment: Thanks! I am truly awful at regexes though, do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: I've added a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler regex that works for you is this:

```
/(?=.*[_!@#$%^&*-])(?=.*\d)(?!.*[.\n])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])^.{8,}$/
```

There were few mistakes in your original regex eg:

- You don't need to use lookahead for making sure there are 8 chars in input
- negative lookahead `[.\n]` was missing `.*`
- `(?=.*\W+)` is superfluous and probably not serving any purpose